# SQL injection with output cursor

Tags: sql, entity-framework, security, sql-injection

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(nKey IN INTEGER, pcResult OUTCustomType) IS
BEGIN
 OPEN pcResult FOR
  SELECT MyPackage.IsBool1(nKey) AS IsBool1,
         MyPackage.IsBool2(nKey) AS IsBool2,
         MyPackage.IsBool3(nKey) AS IsBool3
   FROM DUAL;
END;
```

We have an external team to test security, they use a tool to achieve that.
Our procedure is consumed in our .Net app via EF.

The security report shows that all procedures with a cursor as output have a risk for SQL injection.

Could you please explain me how SQL injection could be exlpoited on pcResult  ?

Thank you for your help,

Bile

Comment: Your SQL statement is not dynamically built and therefore not subject to SQL injection. Besides, it queries `DUAL` so there would be no point trying to get additional data from it. The security tool may (wrongly) assume that all procedures returning cursors use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.